# Closed Captions in YouTube as JSON

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to get closed captions in a youtube clip as json ? I read passing "alt=json" should work, but it doesn't seem to. Any idea ? Also does the CC also work when it is done via translation ? For example
curl "http://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=V6Tsrg_EQMw&lang=en" doesn't return anything (though the clip does have CC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There currently is no supported API for retrieving closed caption tracks for arbitrary videos. (You might be able to reverse-engineer some methods of getting that data, but it's not supported and I can't encourage doing that.)

The officially supported methods for working with captions are for v2 of the YouTube Data API and are documented at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions

Only an authenticated request as the owner of a given video will expose the list of caption tracks and allow you to download them in `.srt` or `.sub` format (not JSON).

I would expect that at some point there will be methods for interacting with captions in v3 of the API, but unfortunately I don't have any specific information to share about when that might happen.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I will look into other methods for now and get back to v3 once it is available.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) to download the captions (as either `srt`, `ass`, `vtt`, or `lrc`).
2. Use [TranscribeFiles' Online Captions & Subtitles Converter](https://transcribefiles.net/other/pages/caption-subtitle-converter.htm) to convert to any of 11 different json schemas.